# ASP.Net Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a ASP.Net website that connects to a MySQL data base to retrieve data. I have used NuGet to install mysql.data. Doing this added a Bin folder with the sql.data dll in it to my project. It added a reference in my web config file. and it added a packages.config to my project. All of this is expected i assume ? With these resources in place my website works when i run it from visual studio. The problem is when i upload it to a server i get the following error :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\bman262\www.brandonsLoginTest.somee.com\riviera horticulture\web.config    Line: 7 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1
```

This is saying it cant find the mysql.data reference right ? What am i doing wrong ?

Here are some pictures of my solution in visual studio and my web.config

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUHA2.png)

[Web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc6ji.png)

I am tearing my hair out over this, any help would be VERY appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone using similar or the same host as me if you have this problem the solution was to convert the project file to an application on the server.

Answer (score 0):

→ You will have to make sure that the same version is installed on the server where you are deploying your project.

→ If the server to which you are deploying your project is on 64 bit, you can enable 32 bit support for this site's application pool, if your dll requires 32 bit architecture.

Comment: The same version of sql.data ?

Comment: I am referring to .net connector. Also, make sure that your dll reside on bin folder in production server

Comment: Ok thank you i will look into this and post my results

Comment: Ok so my project is 4.0 and so is my server ? whats going wrong here ?

Comment: You will need to make sure that mysql .net connector Version=6.9.8.0 is installed on server. You may try following code:

<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"  
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>

Comment: Also, make sure that 32 bit application support is enabled for the application pool which is being used by your site.

Comment: Ok thanks once again for helping me with this, i already have that code in my web config but it still dose not work. Im not really sure what you mean by my application pool though could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Go to your server's IIS >> Sites >>Check basic settings of your site, it will show you the exact application pool being used by your site. Then Go to Application pool tab. Click on advanced settings of the application which your site is using and you will see the list of settings.

Comment: Im hosting my site on Somee.com i dont believe they allow me to access that information and there support ticket system is useless they dont reply, I could link you to the page that has the errors if that would help diagnose the issue ?